# How to motion track/set tracking points for cable/rope

Tags: tracking

How to motion track Cable/Rope in blender, I've managed to do the track for the object which has certain degree of contrast, but the cable/rope has the same features along a curved line in 3D space, if I put tracking points on the rope/wire, then the tracking points will slide back and forth along the curve because they have the same feature along the surface which I do not know how to effectively tracking the cable/rope, my goal is to track the entire calbe/rope and animate the electricity along the cable path, so my issue will be summarized as below:

[image]

1.How to track cable/rope path without the tracking points sliding, the cable/rope is static.

2.Is it a better way to wrap some circle strip every centimeter accorss the cable/rope to have the tracing points fixed on the path if there is no other workaround? Or Mocha has cable/rope tracking capability?

3.Extra issues with regard to the camera solve, if I intially put 12 tracking points from the first frame, and 10 tracking point finally managed to survise the entire frame, which I will have is the 2 died tracking point has a very high error value, and is marked as red(disabled), but the error will be added up to the whole solve error, which I thought as long as it is disabled like from frame 20, then it shouldn't contribute to the whole camera solve error from then on cause it's disabled from frame 20, but now, it seams like even the tracking points are disabled they still take effect on the solve, I want to know how to use this two points only when it is unabled, and completely discard it after disabled.

Comment: Why do you need to track the cables? As long as you have enough elements to track, you should be able to pull a decent reconstruction. Don't limit yourself to only 12 tracking points, track more and let blender evaluate which ones work the best, just make sure that whatever you track, you track accurately. It is hard to help you further without seeing what kind of shot you are dealing with. Please read the following link:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking. For questions about mocha use other sites.

Comment: I can solve the camera by tracking other feature points, but my goal is to animate electricity flow through the cable, so I have to track the cable,

Comment: if you must track the cable you need some feature that is there from frame to  frame, so you might need to add tracking marks (stickers, markers or whatever) on the actual cable.

Comment: Can you add a link to the video?

Comment: It is the same as the picture I listed, a charging cable pluged in the phone, and I take a camera to shoot the footage, my internet connection is bad so I uploaded picture on my question:(

Comment: What matters is the kind of movement you are dealing with, How is the camera moving?

Comment: I combine all possible movement, rotating, forward, backward